# css-стили только для устройств apple

Tags: php, javascript, css3, ios, кроссплатформенность

Появилась необходимость задать отдельные правила css для iOS (скрыть элемент, который в этой ОС не работает). 
Возможно ли это сделать?

Как назвать файл стилей для устройств apple?

Или как прописать медиа запросы конкретно для iOS, если задача решается с их помощью?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется устройства не виноваты... Вам нужно отслеживать не устройства, а браузер с которого заходят. В вашем случае это safari. На js приблизительно так:

```
function get_name_browser(){
// получаем данные userAgent
var ua = navigator.userAgent;    
// с помощью регулярного выражения
// ищем упоминание названия браузера
if (ua.search(/Safari/) > 0) return true;
// Возвращем false если не нашли safari
return false;
}


// Если функция вернула true
// То подключаем css
if (get_name_browser()) {
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/safari.css">');
}
```

Пример для разных брауpеров

```
function get_name_browser(){
    // получаем данные userAgent
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;    
    // с помощью регулярного выражения
    // ищем упоминание названия браузера
    if (ua.search(/Chrome/) > 0) return 'Chrome';
    if (ua.search(/Firefox/) > 0) return 'Firefox';
    if (ua.search(/Opera/) > 0) return 'Opera';
    if (ua.search(/Safari/) > 0) return 'Safari';
    if (ua.search(/MSIE/) > 0) return 'IE';
    return false;
}


// сравниваем название и подключаем нужный css
if (get_name_browser() == "Chrome") {
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Chrome.css">');
}
if (get_name_browser() == "Firefox") {
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Firefox.css">');
}
if (get_name_browser() == "Opera") {
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Opera.css">');
}
if (get_name_browser() == "Safari") {
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/safari.css">');
}
if (get_name_browser() == "IE") {
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/IE.css">');
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! А если я вот так напишу (добавлю проверку на IE дополнительно к safari)? Это будет работать? if (ua.search(/Safari/) > 0) return true;
else if (ua.search(/MSIE/) > 0) return true;
return false;

Comment: Да, только, тогда нужно возвращать не true а например название и сверяться по нему     if (ua.search(/Chrome/) > 0) return 'Google Chrome';
    if (ua.search(/Firefox/) > 0) return 'Firefox';
    if (ua.search(/Opera/) > 0) return 'Opera';
    if (ua.search(/Safari/) > 0) return 'Safari';
    if (ua.search(/MSIE/) > 0) return 'Internet Explorer';

Comment: Это будет правильно? Я крайне поверхностно знакома с js, никогда раньше сама ничего на нем не писала. if (ua.search(/Safari/) > 0) return "Safari";
else if (ua.search(/MSIE/) > 0) return "Internet Explorer";
return false;

if (Safari || Internet Explorer) {
 document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/safari.css">');
}

Comment: @Наталья Обновил ответ

Comment: Очень благодарна Вам за помощь. Пока не могу, к сожалению, со 100%-ной уверенностью сказать, что все у меня отлично получилось. Споткнулась я немножко на префиксах для Safari. Но это уже совсем другая история. Закончу с ними, напишу Вам, как оно работает :))

Comment: Всё работает на УРА! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Нашла возможность добавлять в head ссылку на отдельный файл.css только в том случае, если страница открывается с айфона. Пока не успела опробовать, но, на всякий случай, напишу, куда копать, если появилась такая задача.

Перед открывающим html пишется код запроса сервером (насколько я понимаю) браузера пользователя:

```
<php
    $browser=strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone');
      if(browser==true){
      $browser='iphone';}
?>
```

Далее в секции head указываем ссылку на файл iphone-style.css, которая будет использоваться только в случае, если пользователь просматривает сайт с айфона:

```
<?php
   if ($browser=='iphone'){?>
     echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='iphone-style.css'>"
<?php }?>
```

И, наконец, в файле iphone-style.css указываем нужные конкретно для iOS стили.

Поскольку я в пхп не понимаю ничего, поправьте, если что-то тут неправильно.
А практический результат я напишу завтра, - заработает или нет.